# Raphael.js -- the script seems light, but the execution is heavy -- why?

Tags: browser, raphael, repaint, motion, reflow

I am using Raphael 2.01, Firefox 12.0, on Windows XP.

I've tried continuous object motion (not tween animation). I think the load by my script is light, but the sound of the PC's cooling fan will be loud!

I want to know the reason and solution.

(steps)

- I set several circle objects (5 to 10) on the document.
- They move on. When they touch the edge of the document, they return(move opposite direction), but their motion will slow down.
- When I check the PC's load in Google Chrome's task manager,
  the memory usage becomes bigger and bigger (40MB ===> 150MB ===> ... )

(script)

http://jsfiddle.net/JsL46/3/

*** Sorry. When I paste the code to the "jsfiddle", circle objects appear but they do not run.

Comment: after messing about with the jsFiddle, it seems the memory leak is the least of your problems. debug, refactor and correct the script, than ask a more concise question.

Comment: Thank you Eliran, and sorry for my late reply. I think "translate()" consumes a lot memory, and it is better way to choice 
the function "animate()" to make memory consumption lower. But this method effects mathematical motion description of the lines very well. So I learn more about Raphael scheme.

Answer (score 0):

RaphaelJS does animation using traditional style changes and offsets, which causes alot and [repaints and reflows](http://gent.ilcore.com/2011/03/how-not-to-trigger-layout-in-webkit.html). Use [SVG SMIL animation](http://www.svgopen.org/2008/presentations/70-Tricks_of_Javascript_and_declarative_animation/index.html) to reduce the load on the browser for simple cases such as [left/right movement](http://srufaculty.sru.edu/david.dailey/svg/ovaling.svg).